# Trigonometry and convergence of angles

Tags: java, scala, trigonometry, angle

here's my problem:

2 angles represented as integer from 0 to 360 (or 359 if needed)
1 double from 0 to 1, representing the convergence rate.

I need to write a function which pulls the angles close together by a factor equal to the convergence rate.

For example, if i have a converge rate of 0.5 and two angles: 80° and 40°, the output should be a couple of angles 70° and 50° (so that they are halfway from the converging angle of 60°). Thi is fairly obvious with this configuration but it's hard for me to approach the problem in a general case, because i'm really bad at trigonometry and never worked with angles in my career, so i have no experience. So this function needs to work with any configuration of angles and the problem arise because for example, if the difference is >180, i need to invert the operations because the angles are represented as integers and i must work with sum and subtraction

I need to implement it in Scala but feel free to write your suggestion in Java, pseudo-code or any other popular language, i hope there won't be issues on translating your code to Scala.

The lighter the solution, the better.

Comment: @dhg i found a function to calculate the difference, adjusted to the rate and then i had to write the condition to select which angle should be increased and which one decreased.

Comment: @alex23 a general explanation would suffice or pseudo code. I just wrote the languages if anyone was interested in writing the code directly instead of explaining, but obviously it wasn't what i was requesting

Answer (score 1):

Original Angles = o1 o2.

Difference D= o2-o1 (taking care this is positive, suppose o1 < o2)

Mid Angle M= o1 + (D/2)

Convergence factor = F

New Angles = M +- (D/2)*F

If I am correct this is what is required.Since the angles are always between 0-360 and assuming that you need to only go anticlockwise to find the mid values and all.

Comment: yes and no. the logic behind the +- is my problem, because it's not obvious

Comment: Why so ? can you please explain using values?

Comment: why a -1 ?Please atleast leave a comment to explain a -1

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation produced by a friend of mine. I know it's ***shitty*** scala code but he wrote it in imperative pseudocode and i haven't converted it to functional but it's a fair solution. Tested on a bunch of inputs and seems fine.

```
  def adjustAngles(aa1: Int, aa2: Int):(Int,Int)= {
        def convergenceRate=0.5
      var diff = aa2 - aa1;
      var a1 = aa1
      var a2 = aa2
      if (diff > 180) {
        diff -= 360;
      } else if (diff < -180) {
        diff += 360;
      }

      a1 = ((a1 + diff / 2 * convergenceRate) % 360).toInt; 
      if (a1 < 0) {
        a1 += 360;
      }

      a2 = ((a2 - diff / 2 * convergenceRate) % 360).toInt
      if (a2 < 0) {
        a2 += 360;
      }
      (a1, a2)
    }
```